# How to send some objects of case class to another computer by ip and port easily?

Tags: scala, sockets

I want to exchange some objects of case class to another computer, by ip and port. There are several possible approaches (e.g. Plain socket server, http server, RMI...)

But I want to know is there any simple solution can do this job, in Scala?

Comment: Could look into Akka actors?

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice project named [scala/pickling](https://github.com/scala/pickling) which make  serialization/deserialization very easy.

From the pickling site:
"Scala Pickling is an automatic serialization framework made for Scala. It's fast, boilerplate-free, and allows users to easily swap in/out different serialization formats (such as binary, or JSON), or even to provide your own custom serialization format."

It support serialization/deserialization from both Json and binary formats, so it makes it very easy to transfer to another machine, either using Web-service, or using binary communication.